# CMake print progress and build time

Tags: cmake, gfortran

I am compiling a fairly large Fortran program using gfortran. It takes roughly 5 minutes to compile on a single processor on my laptop. I started with a hand written `Makefile` which would print almost everything it was doing to the screen. It also printed the amount of time it took to build upon completion.

I have since moved to CMake and I found that a clean build would print bracketed percentages as progress (e.g. `[ XX%]`) but it no longer prints the completion time. When rebuilding, it gives me almost nothing except the last

```
[100%] Buildt target <Project Name>
```

and it still takes about the same amount of time to build.

I would like it to display both percent progress and the completion time on every build.

So here are my questions:

How do I print the build time?
Why doesn't progress (or anything for that matter) print when I rebuild a project?
How do I get some indicator of progress to appear on every build?

Comment: Uhm. Can you just wrap `make` call with `time`?

Comment: Can you explain how (for Windows and Unix)? What was make using before that printed the time that CMake is not using?

Comment: Ah, if `make` have been doing this for you automatically, you can try to run `make VERBOSE=1` in binary or dir, or setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cmake property like this:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time") set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time")
```

then you will get result like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can alternatively use a `zsh` theme that show how much time you spent on a single process. for e.g using `powerlevel10k` theme. 
 
[Powerlevel10k github](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k)
[image: powerlevel10k on alacritty]